# How to view PDF file in an iframe using onsenui and google docs pdf viewer?

Tags: html, google-docs, onsen-ui, x-frame-options

Why do I get the following error when I use google docs viewer inside an iframe in `onsenui`?

ERROR

```
Refused to display 'https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
```

CODE

```
<div class="card">
      <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf" height="200" width="300"></iframe>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

**I just realized that it still give the same error even in plain html without using onen.**

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that the issue is not about onsen. In order to view the pdf file, it just need to add `&embedded=true` in the url.

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:100%; height:1000px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```